# Change value from specific line and column given by user UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, awk, replace

I have this file:

```
 16492674422392|Alberto|Parra|female|1985-09-22|2012-09-01T01:30:59.228+0000|190.96.12.239|Chrome
> 16492674424948|Peng|Chen|female|1984-07-26|2012-09-23T00:51:52.900+0000|1.4.10.198|Internet
> Explorer
> 16492674425075|Changpeng|Xu|female|1984-03-27|2012-10-02T03:55:00.946+0000|1.50.15.119|Firefox
> 16492674425398|Prince|Kobayashi|male|1989-08-07|2012-09-30T03:30:41.772+0000|14.101.89.18|Chrome
> 16492674426410|Yang|Wei|male|1980-07-01|2012-10-01T13:11:48.528+0000|27.144.204.193|Firefox
```

I want the user to:

1. choose an id (id is the first column)
2. choose a column and
3. change the value to one value chosen by the user.

I use:

```
./tool.sh 16492674426410 3 replacement
```

as the inputs, and the code I run is:

```
awk -v antik1=$1 -v antik2=$2 '
{
    sub(antik1, antik2);
    print;
}' persons.dat.txt
```

This script doesn't let the user choose the column and id. How can I modify it so it works as I want?

Comment: Are the `>` signs part of the file? Are your columns defined/delimited by `|` characters? Is there really a line with only `> Explorer` in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Give this tested version a try:

```
#!/bin/bash --

awk -v anid="${1}" -v antik1="${2}" -v antik2="${3}" '    
BEGIN {
  FS="|";
  OFS="|";
}
{
  if ($1 == anid) {
    $antik1=antik2;
  }
  print;
}' persons.dat.txt
```

The test:

```
$ ./tool.sh 16492674426410 3 replacement
16492674422392|Alberto|Parra|female|1985-09-22|2012-09-01T01:30:59.228+0000|190.96.12.239|Chrome
16492674424948|Peng|Chen|female|1984-07-26|2012-09-23T00:51:52.900+0000|1.4.10.198|Internet Explorer
16492674425075|Changpeng|Xu|female|1984-03-27|2012-10-02T03:55:00.946+0000|1.50.15.119|Firefox
16492674425398|Prince|Kobayashi|male|1989-08-07|2012-09-30T03:30:41.772+0000|14.101.89.18|Chrome
16492674426410|Yang|replacement|male|1980-07-01|2012-10-01T13:11:48.528+0000|27.144.204.193|Firefox
```